# Handiling disconnected Sockets

Tags: java, android, sockets

I have implemented socket in my app and ofcourse it's communicating with server and my problem is I am not able to identify when the socket goes down in following scenarios.

1) iam connected to wifi having an active internet connection and have active socket connection and my internet connection goes down

2) when am connected to 2g/3g internet connection , sometimes socket connection goes down

In above conditions i am not able to identify whether there is an active socket connection.Is there any method for achieving this in android?

please help...

Comment: All I can say is using `broadcast receiver` for internet connection or try to read from `InputStream`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at Android's [Determining and Monitoring the Connectivity Status](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html):

> You can use the [ConnectivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html) to check that you're actually connected to the Internet, and if so, what type of connection is in place.

There's some example code:

```
ConnectivityManager cm =
        (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null &&
                      activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
```

Also,

> The ConnectivityManager broadcasts the CONNECTIVITY_ACTION ("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE") action whenever the connectivity details have changed. You can register a broadcast receiver in your manifest to listen for these changes and resume (or suspend) your background updates accordingly.
>
> ```
> <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
> ```

Comment: No, but this was explicitly created for the exact situations you're trying to handle. Is it not working for you?

Comment: it's ok if my connection drops or if iam changing from one connection to another connection ..but that was not my scenario..i've tried this but not working